# Generate users and send send password

Tags: php, security, hash

i have such problem.
I need to generate users from CVS data, and then send email to user with his login,and password, not at the moment of generation. The problem is, password are hashed and i can only check it, not grab it from database. I have only solution with another table/base with just login/password for the email, without hashing, but it is wrong from the point of view of safety and security. Maybe someone had such task?

Comment: When you have hashed passwords, the only approach to "send a user his password" is to create a new one, save the hash in the database and send the password to the user. And this should stay the only way to do it. ;)

Comment: as @bluszcz answered, the best thing to do is to let user generate their own password. The trend is to never know your user's password. Less problems for you

Comment: encode and save the password in separate field at the time of send email decode the password sent to user and null the field.

Comment: seems i will do like Kathiravan said

Comment: @Kathiravan Wait, but you mentioned that you "I can only check it". If its true, then you simply CAN'T send the password - because you don't know it. To do it - you would have to bruteforce all hashes to guess. Or your question was not clear enough.

Comment: bluszcz, no when i generating users i know the password, but i later i cant grab it from hash, and i need to send letters later.

Answer (score 0):

Send them a link where they will be able to set their new password - I guess this will be most secure.

Comment: and you believe that user will do that? :))

Comment: If you consider user's security - then usually users consider your service as a proofed one. I don't like password coming in plain text emails, or services who knows my password...